# How to get a multiple line plot from a list of lists

Tags: plotting

Following this data input

```
{{{2,4,6,8,9},{342432,435345,564564,56756,9945},{23,356,565,304,564},{3,67,76,44,7}}}
```

The array is the data of three lines.  The first line is the timeline Independent variable ( 5 separate time frames)

I need to plot  three lines with the ordinate x axis been the first list of the matrix .   Notice that there is a second and thirds parenthesis that increase the need to be flatten the data list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose input data is:

```
lst = {{2, 4, 6, 8, 9}, {342432, 435345, 564564, 56756, 9945}, {23, 356, 565, 304, 564}, {3, 67, 76, 44, 7}}
```

then using following code give 3 plots

```
ListLinePlot[MapThread[List, {lst[[1]], #}]] & /@ lst[[2 ;;]]
```

PS: if you work with time series probably better use more specific approach with construction `TimeSeries` and using `DateListPlot` instead of `ListLinePlot`

Answer (score 6):

If I understood your question correctly this is what you want.

```
data = Flatten[{{{2, 4, 6, 8, 9}, {342432, 435345, 564564, 56756, 9945}, {23, 356, 565, 304, 564}, {3, 67, 76, 44, 7}}}, 1];
ListLogPlot[Transpose[{data[[1]], #}] & /@ data[[2 ;;]], Joined -> True]
```

[image]